# How to configure a Rebus endpoint to run as a service

Tags: rebus

I am trying to use Topshelf to create a Rebus endpoint that will run as a service.  How should this be set up and are there any examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Rebus samples repository](https://github.com/rebus-org/RebusSamples), where the [integration service sample](https://github.com/rebus-org/RebusSamples/tree/master/Integration/IntegrationSample.IntegrationService) in particular shows what you're after.

As you can see in [Program.cs](https://github.com/rebus-org/RebusSamples/blob/master/Integration/IntegrationSample.IntegrationService/Program.cs) it uses Topshelf to basically just hold on to a Windsor container, which it disposes when the application shuts down.

The Castle Windsor [installer syntax](https://github.com/rebus-org/RebusSamples/blob/master/Integration/IntegrationSample.IntegrationService/Program.cs#L37) causes the installers to be automatically picked up, where the [RebusInstaller](https://github.com/rebus-org/RebusSamples/blob/master/Integration/IntegrationSample.IntegrationService/Installers/RebusInstaller.cs) shows how you'd typically let Rebus inject itself into your container, and the [HandlerInstaller](https://github.com/rebus-org/RebusSamples/blob/master/Integration/IntegrationSample.IntegrationService/Installers/HandlerInstaller.cs) shows how you can add handlers to the container.

It should be fairly easy to adapt the sample to use another container - just remember to dispose it when the application shuts down, thus giving Rebus a chance to finish messages currently being handled and stop its worker threads.

Comment: Thanks Mogens, that's exactly what I was after.  My search-fu is weakening lately! ;)