# How to run Rebus endpoint with a generic host

Tags: generics, host, servicebus, bus, rebus

I have implemented a Rebus endpoint as a service following this post ([How to configure a Rebus endpoint to run as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828099/how-to-configure-a-rebus-endpoint-to-run-as-a-service)) but I'm wondering if there is a generic host application for Rebus like other bus services like NServiceBus, MassTransit, Shuttle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did play around with [Topshelf](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf) [at some point](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.Hosting) with the ambition to create a generic host, but I never got around to actually make it usable.

I'll definitely get around to finish it some time later, but these things usually arrive faster when I need it myself or someone else who is up to the task ;)

PS: If you have any questions e.g. regarding how you can build your own host, please don't hesitate to ask :)